# How many times is this loop body repeated?

Tags: java, loops, language-agnostic

In my Object-Oriented Programming course we discussed a topic that I don't think he ever named, I've tried to find out what it's name is to find a proper way to solve these, but I have had no luck.

This is not homework, but a question for clarification about the process to solve this problem.

```
for I = (N + 2) downto -1
    for J = (I - 1) to (N + 4)
        // Code is run here
```

The question is "How many times is `// Code is run here` ran?"

Here is what I have tried to solve this:

1) `I = (N + 2)`, `J = [(N + 2) - 1]` from this (and what I remember) you use `b - a - 1` to solve for the number of times executed, which gives us `X = [(N + 2) - 1] - (N + 2) - 1` which can be simplified to `X = -2`

2) `I = -1`, `J =`((-1) - 1)`and`X = ((-1) - 1) - (-1) - 1`which simplifies to`X = -2`

I'm getting lost on dealing with the second `for` loop and how to finish the problem. I know that we have to end up with an answer such as `r(r + 1)/2`

I just want to say that I have attempted to look for a name of this type of technique, but he simply called it "Code Counting" which didn't return any searches relating to this topic.

Thank you

EDIT: This course was in Java, so that is why I used the Java tag for this question, if anyone is curious.

EDIT2: To clarify, this was on a ***written exam***, so we are expected to do this via pen-and-paper, I would like an explanation of how to solve this question as I have attempted it many times and still end up with the wrong answer.

Comment: are the `to` boundaries inclusive?

Comment: Can you not just do the classic physicist approach of getting the answer and working backwards? Just put a counter in loop I, then isolate loop J and do the same. Hopefully a counter in loop IJ should give you the  counter in J * counter in I .

Comment: By any chance, did you mean `O notation`?

Comment: I would assume so, here is the answer that we are expected to conclude with: `(N + 7)(N + 8) / 2 - 6`

EDIT: @gian1200 I guess it can be related to it, but we only briefly discussed Big-O Notation in the course and he never connected the two to each other.

Comment: @user2589273 It is not code to be put in an IDE an ran, but rather a problem to be solved by hand on paper.

Comment: seems like my answer is quite close to that expected solution ;)

Comment: close, but I am asking for a detailed explanation of the correct answer, not an answer **close** to it.

Comment: Looking at the expected the solution the bounds seem to be inclusive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the "code" and start counting logically. In the first iteration of the outer loop (called OL) you execute the inner loop (IL) `(N + 4) - (N + 2 - 1) + 1` times `= 4` times.

*Explanation of the +1*: if we run the loop from -1 to 2, we in fact run it 4 times: -1, 0, 1, 2, which in math is `2 - (-1) + 1.

The next time `I = N + 1`, therefore the IL runs `(N + 4) - (N + 1 - 1) + 1` times `= 5` times. Same goes for the next step and the step after that, the times the IL is executed increase by one each time : `4 + 5 + 6 + ...`. The question remaining is how far we go.

The last step is `I = -1`, there IL gets run `(N + 4) - (-1 - 1) + 1 = N + 7` times.

The sum you are looking for therefore seems to be `4 + 5 + 6 + ... + (N + 6) + (N + 7)`. Which in fact is something like `r(r + 1)/2` with a few substractions and additions.

*The above numbers assume the `to` boundaries to be inclusive.*

Note: whenever you come up with some kind of a formular, choose the input parameter as something small (like 0 or 1) and verify that the formula works for that value.

Summing the values using the little gaussian formula `r * (r + 1) / 2` we have `r -> N + 7`. And therefore `(N + 7) * (N + 8) / 2`. But then we count the 3, 2 and 1 as well, which are actually not in the above listing, we need to subtract them and come to the final solution of:

```
(N + 7) * (N + 8) / 2 - 6
```

Comment: I posted the answer to this question under your comment on my original post, the answer is supposed to be: `[(N + 7)(N + 8) / 2] - 6` but I am not able to completely figure out how this could be.

Comment: @liquidsystem well, my current solution would be `(N + 6)(N + 7) / 2 - 3` which is pretty damn close. I am guessing the difference is the exact question i previously asked about the inclusion of the bounds.

Comment: We never discussed whether he would give us problems inclusively or exclusively, so I'd like to assume it's exclusive. Also, I was wondering if the equation that he told us to use, `b-a-1` is correct and how to use that to "shorten" the amount of time to walk through this loop?

Comment: @luk2302 so is the idea here to look at the IL before the OL here? In the past we've had both loops go UP to a value, instead of one DOWN to and one UP to.

Comment: @liquidsystem the idea here is to take the outer loop value for granted and look at the inner loop. check how often that is run, then make one step in the outer loop and check how often the inner loop runs. You need to find a pattern in the runtimes of the inner loop - That is it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98950/discussion-between-liquidsystem-and-luk2302).

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm as shown in the question looks like the good old Basic syntax

```
for X down/to Y, that includes Y
```

The outer loop goes from `n+2` to `-1`, so the inner loop goes

```
n+1 to n+4 =>   4 iterations
...
 -2 to n+4 => n+7 iterations
```

Summing all of these, we get

```
n+3
 ∑ (4+i)  =  4(n+4) + (n+3)(n+4) / 2
i=0
          =  (n+11)(n+4) / 2
```

which is also equal to `(N + 7)(N + 8) / 2 - 6`

Comment: Right, just the general idea of getting this imprinted into my mind for memorization is the tricky part, as we only briefly discussed this idea and then proceeded to continue with other topics, it was a pain because the last few quizzes included questions such as this one and caused me to lose points because of it!

Comment: The most tricky part is to make no mistake in the inner iteration calculation, then for that kind of problem, the `sum(1 to N) = N(N+1)/2` equation is used a lot. This is probably the main equation to remember.